# Firebase Funtions push notifications

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to firebase and there is something I can't do. I want to send a notification to the phone with firebase functions. I want to receive notifications on the phone when someone follows me. My Firebase collection is as in the photo. I want to access the Followers array and send its information with notification. The codes I could write are as follows. What do I need to add?

[image]

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.firestore.document('/users/{uid}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  var values = snap.data();
  var token = values.fcmTokens;     
  
  var payload = {
    notification: {
      title: values.title,
      body: values.message
      }    
  }   
  
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `onCreate()` function is triggered when a document is created. I assume followers array will be updated everytime someone follows a user?  In that case you should be using `onUpdate()` that'll trigger the function when the document is updated. You can just check if length of `followers` array has changed in the update, if yes then send the notification as shown below:

```
exports.sendPushNotification = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const newValue = change.after.data();
    const previousValue = change.before.data();

    if (newValue.followers.length > previousValue.followers.length) {
      // followers count increased, send notification
      const token = newValue.fcmTokens;

      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: "New Follower",
          body: "Someone followed you"
        }
      }

      await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
    }

    return null;
  });
```

Here, we send notification only if the followers field has changed since this function will trigger whenever any field in this user document is updated.

If you want to specify who followed the user, then you'll have to find the new UID added in followers array and query that user's data.

---

Firestore documents have a max size limit of `1 MB` so if a user can have many followers then I'll recommend creating a followers sub-collection. Then you'll be able to use `onCreate()` on the sub-document path `/users/{userId}/followers/{followerId}`

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I normally work with Flutter. I don't know anything about Java. That's why I had to ask. And I don't know how to access the Uid inside.

Comment: @TolunayKurt inside the cloud functions? Assuming the document ID in users collection is user's Firebase Auth UID then that'll be `const userId = context.params.userId`.

Comment: If I send you an e-mail, can you inform me about it?

Comment: And I did what you said, I didn't get the notification

Comment: @Dharmaraj it is supposed to be `newValue.followers.length > previousValue.followers.length` instead of `newValue.followers.length > newValue.followers.length` please correct it.

Comment: Thanks @ObumunemeNwabude. Missed it after copying the same/ Fixed it.